# Pandas - Find the outlier row between two dataframes when only looking at certain columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes - one which is edited by users from a powerapp. The other which comes directly from onedrive.

The columns headers are almost the same and I need to compare the two dataframes and add any new rows into the dataframe which comes from powerapps. Here are two example dataframes:

Powerapps dataframe:

```
          Send/Collect            Hospital   Courier                      Kit                      Manufacturer  Status
0                Send     Nuffield Ipswich   Courier  ActivMotion (HTO - DFO)        NewClip Hire Log 2018.xlsx  Not Started
1                 Send         BMI Rosshal   Courier  ActivMotion (HTO - DFO)        NewClip Hire Log 2018.xlsx  In Progress
2              Collect       Stepping Hill   Courier  ActivMotion (HTO - DFO)        NewClip Hire Log 2018.xlsx  Not Started
3              Collect       York District  Courier   ActivMotion (HTO - DFO)        NewClip Hire Log 2018.xlsx  Not Started
4  Royal Devon Exeter                  NaN       NaN  ActivMotion (HTO - DFO)        NewClip Hire Log 2018.xlsx  Not Started
5              collect       Spire Bristol  Courier   ActivMotion (HTO - DFO)        NewClip Hire Log 2018.xlsx  Complete
6                 Send         Bridlington  Courier        ToeMotion - MTP DF  Arthrosurface Hire Log 2018.xlsx  Not Started
7   Send Femoral Head    Hampshire Clinic        DHL             Human Tissue             Human Tissue Log.xlsx   Not Started
```

Onedrive dataframe:

```
          Send/Collect            Hospital   Courier                      Kit                      Manufacturer
0                Send     Nuffield Ipswich   Courier  ActivMotion (HTO - DFO)        NewClip Hire Log 2018.xlsx
1                 Send         BMI Rosshal   Courier  ActivMotion (HTO - DFO)        NewClip Hire Log 2018.xlsx
2              Collect       Stepping Hill   Courier  ActivMotion (HTO - DFO)        NewClip Hire Log 2018.xlsx
3              Collect       York District  Courier   ActivMotion (HTO - DFO)        NewClip Hire Log 2018.xlsx
4  Royal Devon Exeter                                 ActivMotion (HTO - DFO)        NewClip Hire Log 2018.xlsx
5              collect       Spire Bristol  Courier   ActivMotion (HTO - DFO)        NewClip Hire Log 2018.xlsx
6  Royal Devon Exeter                                 ActivMotion (HTO - DFO)        NewClip Hire Log 2018.xlsx
7                 Send         Bridlington  Courier        ToeMotion - MTP DF  Arthrosurface Hire Log 2018.xlsx
8   Send Femoral Head    Hampshire Clinic        DHL             Human Tissue             Human Tissue Log.xlsx
```

As you can see, the powerapps dataframe has a different column (which can contain different values, not only just "not started") whilst the onedrive dataframe has an extra row (that needs to go into the powerapps df).

Also note, whilst from the onedrive dataframe empty cells are a string "", but from powerapps it is nan.

I need to merge the extra row from onedrive to powerapps (adding status of "Not Started" to that row). I think i need a method that will merge based on similarities found in column 0,3 and 4 whilst ignoring columns 1,2 and 5. How would i do this?

Comment: I like the background of your picture , but I can not help since it is pic ..

Comment: sorry it is a pycharm thing! lemme run it on idle and i will edit

Comment: @Wen edited now - hopefully this will be easier for you!

Comment: Are you only trying to merge the missing rows from onedrive to powerapps, or are you trying to make changes to onedrive as well? It is not completely clear to me at the moment.

Comment: I'm trying to add the missing row from onedrive to powerapps @d_kennetz

Answer (score 0):

I think concat fits here

```
#replacing all the spaces with nan in the onedrive dataframe
onedrive.replace('""', 'nan') #use np.nan accordingly
powerapp = pd.concat([onedrive, powerapp])

powerapp.Status.fillna('Not Started', inplace=True)
```

Drop the redundant data based on subset of columns. 

Note : Reset the index after concatinating